# Moving files based on numbers in filename - python

Tags: python, sorting, file-copying

I have hundreds of image files in a folder named in the style "imagefile_xxxx.fit" where xxxx is a number, and corresponding data files, one for every image, in the style "datafile_xxxx.cat".

I've written a python programme that loops through all my data files and moves bad data to a directory of undesirables based on how many lines of data, and I want to then move the corresponding image file out of its directory to a folder of bad images, based on the number in the filenames.

So if datafile_0012.cat has been moved to the directory bad_data, move imagefile_0012.fit to the directory bad_images.

I am considering doing it the other way (copy good data to a directory and leave good and bad files mixed together in the original directory), but I still have the problem of copying image files based on the number in the data file name.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint :

```
bdfn = "datafile_0012.cat"
bifn = bdfn.replace("datafile", "imagefile")
print(bifn)
```

Results in :

> imagefile_0012.cat

Comment: And use this to create a list of files I want to move, of course. Thank you.

Comment: @J.Blue Yes, or copy files on the fly if you don't have consistency constraints.